# ¿Hay alguna manera de eliminar una respuesta definitivamente?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, eliminación-de-respuestas

Hay algunas respuestas que son eliminadas. Por lo general, para los usuarios que no tienen el privilegio, no se ven dichas respuestas.

Sin embargo, hay a algunos usuarios (si has conseguido el privilegio para ver respuestas eliminadas) que se les muestran dichas respuestas aun siendo eliminadas.

Hasta aquí lo veo relativamente bien, para que la gente pueda ver en qué no deben recaer a la hora de realizar una respuesta.

Sin embargo, hay algunas respuestas que tienen SPAM, publicidad, emails con el fin de que les envíes algún tipo de información, etc que, la verdad, creo que dejándolas ahí simplemente, pueden ser un foco de publicidad u otras acciones fraudulentas ya que los usuarios que tienen el privilegio también pueden acceder a ellas. Por supuesto es decisión de cada uno hacerles caso o no, pero como diría el dicho, "más vale prevenir que curar".

**EDICIÓN:** Como no está muy claro de si se trata de un bug o no, finalmente voy a insertar las imágenes correspondientes (que me proporcionó Mariano, ¡gracias!) en la pregunta para que se puedan ver los diferentes comportamientos:

En el navegador, antes de la edición de @rnd, se veía con el siguiente texto (lo he tenido que coger de las ediciones ya que ahora no lo podía visualizar en rojo como se visualizaba al principio):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la versión móvil se veía así:

[image]

Como podéis observar, en la versión móvil el texto se oculta mientras que en la versión de escritorio ha sido necesaria una edición manual para que el texto no se viera.

¿Habría alguna manera de eliminar completamente dichas respuestas?
¿Qué opináis sobre eliminar definitivamente este tipo de respuestas y que ningún usuario pueda verlas?

Comment: Prácticamente esto ya está implementado: [Remove links when a post is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131026/209901)

Comment: @fedorqui Mira por ejemplo esta respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36949/agregar-filas-din%C3%A1micas-a-un-tabla-con-datos-extra%C3%ADdos-de-mysql/41123#41123. Sin embargo, desde el móvil (comprobado por Mariano) se ve bien: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOwCO.jpg

Comment: No tengo reputación suficiente para ver las respuestas borradas, pero lo que comentas tiene pinta de bug. Sugiero editar la pregunta dando capturas de pantalla de este caso concreto. Esto ayudará, pues a los moderadores y empleados de [se] se les muestra la publicación original, sin el texto alternativo.

Comment: @fedorqui Vale, luego la edito y adjunto capturas y la etiqueto también como bug.

Comment: ¡JAJAJAJ! ¡ese texto está para no creer!

Comment: Aunque no puedes eliminar una respuesta definitivamente lo que sí puedes hacer es que SO quite tu nombre de la respuesta.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos pero realmente en este caso no pregunto por respuestas propias si no por las respuestas que contienen spam u otras acciones fraudulentas.

Answer (score 3):

> Sin embargo, hay algunas respuestas que tienen SPAM, publicidad, emails con el fin de que les envíes algún tipo de información, etc que, la verdad, creo que dejándolas ahí simplemente, pueden ser un foco de publicidad u otras acciones fraudulentas ya que los usuarios que tienen el privilegio también pueden acceder a ellas. Por supuesto es decisión de cada uno hacerles caso o no, pero como diría el dicho, "más vale prevenir que curar".

En este caso la respuesta fue eliminado por un moderador (@Luiggi), por lo tanto, la respuesta original quedo tal como era, sin el cartel indicando que se trata de spam y el correspondiente remplazo del texto original.

La buena noticia es que...  **puedes editar la pregunta/respuesta aunque este eliminada** (ya lo hice) y hacer menos visible el contenido no deseado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la edición. Sin embargo, sigo sin entender que no haya ninguna manera de borrar definitivamente ese tipo de respuestas para que nadie pueda acceder a ellas.

Comment: @Error404 los moderadores pueden borrar "definitivamente" revisiones de ser necesario. Pero se reserva para borrar contraseñas o información sensible. Imagino que tiene alguna utilidad conservar estas respuestas, al menos con fines historicos y estadisticos.

Comment: @rnd creo que incluso cuando los moderadores lo eliminan con flags de spam, debería ocultar el texto. De hecho, la respuesta en cuestión se ve con el mensaje de spam en el sitio mobile, pero no en el sitio desktop.

Comment: @Mariano De momento dejo abierta la pregunta catalogada como bug por si acaso. Ya he hecho la edición de la pregunta con toda la información que tenemos hasta el momento.

Comment: @Error404 ok... Aclaro igual que yo no estoy 100% seguro de qué comportamiento debería tener cuando lo elimina un moderador, o si tiene que tener una cierta cantidad de flags cuando lo elimina

Comment: @Mariano Sí, aunque ante la duda... prefiero marcarlo como posible bug y que nos corrijan en caso de no ser así.

Comment: El cartel se añade si hay al menos un reporte de spam válido. Por tanto, el comportamiento indicado para futuras ocasiones es que el moderador la reporte así antes de eliminarla. Yo hago esto en el sitio en el que soy moderador y funciona bien.

Comment: @fedorqui Sin embargo es extraño que en algunos casos se muestre directamente para la versión de escritorio: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24391/pasar-argumentos-a-ejecutable-exe-c/24397#24397 y para esta no. Además, es también muy raro que la misma respuesta se muestren en escritorio normal y en móvil con el mensaje de que se ha marcado como spam.