# Ciertos sombreros hacen que las fechas se encabalguen con la columna de la derecha

Tags: bug, winterbash-2016, perfil

Estaba leyendo [una respuesta de rnd](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1234/83) cuando me di cuenta que el formato de la fecha queda algo roto, pues se sale del marco de la respuesta en sí y prácticamente se encabalga con la columna de *Preguntas populares en la red*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Sería posible corregirlo para que visualmente esté más armónico? Tengo la sensación de que esto tiene que ver con los sombreros del Winter Bash, que hacen que el texto se desplace sensiblemente a la derecha.
Para comprobarlo hice una prueba cambiándome el sombrero y visualizando [una respuesta mía](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1246/83):

Con sombrero poco invasivo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con sombrero muy invasivo -nótese que "respondida" empieza mucho más a la derecha:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Disculpad la falta de círculos rojos para hacerlo más evidente... no tengo ningún editor a mano :)

Comment: En el día [8 de enero](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1160/6491) se eliminara por si mismo el `bug`

Comment: @aldanux y volverá el 20 de diciembre de 2017 :)

Comment: Podríamos apostar si hasta allí se ha eliminado ese `bug`... una cervezita que no... :)

Comment: @aldanux yo creo que si le ofrecemos un Twingo a Konamiman, lo mismo lo soluciona antes :D

Comment: jajaja... quizás quizás...

Comment: El bug del lado oscuro de la fuerza.