# Los sombreros mueven la fecha de edición en las preguntas, quedando por detrás del perfil del OP

Tags: bug, winterbash-2018

No hay mucho más que añadir: La palabra *editada* suele estar encima del avatar, pero el sombrero ha obligado a añadir:

```css
margin-left:37px !important,
```

Lo que hace que la fecha se salga del perfil:

[image: Los sombreros mueven la fecha de edición en las preguntas]

Comment: El 2 de enero estará solucionado este problema :P

Comment: @lois6b eso de elegir la inacción a la espera de que las cosas se solucionen solas me suena mucho...de algun politico creo.

Comment: Esto habria que comentarlo en [meta.se]. Para este año no se si lo arreglarán o tendrán más cuidado el próximo..

Comment: Similar: [Ciertos sombreros hacen que las fechas se encabalguen con la columna de la derecha](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1247/83), de 2016.